# The ASPNETCoreModule which is required to host .NET Core projects in IIS does not appear to be installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've just installed `Visual Studio 2015` and have just created new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` project. When I run the `ASP.NET Core Web application` project I've met the following exception(I am just hitting `Ctrl+F5` to run the project in Visual Studio 2015):

> The ASPNETCoreModule which is required to host .NET Core projects in
>   IIS does not appear to be installed. Try repairing Visual Studio to
>   correct the problem.

If I run other types of projects such as `ASP.NET MVC` or `ASP.NET Web API`, then they run perfectly.

The following SDK is already installed:

[image]

My `project.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

**What I've tried to do:**

1. **I have varied `version` attribute to `1.0.0-preview2-final`, `1.0.1`, `1.0.3` :**

   `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
     "version": "1.0.3",//1.
     "type": "platform"
   },`
2. **I have installed `DotNetCore.1.0.4_1.1.1-WindowsHosting`:**

[image]

3. **I have repaired Visual Studio 2015 Professional twice.**

*Does anybody know what I should do to fix the problem? 
Any help would be greatly apreciated*

Comment: You trying to run it in IIS?

Comment: @Tseng I am just hitting Ctrl+F5 to run the project

Comment: And you are really using ASP.NET Core 1.0 and not 1.1 (see dependency section of project.json)? `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is a meta package for most runtime related libraries (usually most common `System.*` assemblies) and tells which version of the runtime to use. If you use ASP.NET Core 1.1 you also need a .NET Core 1.1.x runtime (1.1.0 or 1.1.1 iirc)

Comment: I've attached my `package.json` file to the question to avoid misunderstandings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue I got and made simple changes in my Project. 1]Go to Project properties and click on debug tab.
2]Now select IIS from Launch and save 
3]Build the project and run.

Answer (score 10):

I got this error in Visual Studio 2019 and my solution was to run the VS installer and verify that the ASP.NET workload was installed. In my case it was not, simply installing it resolved the issue.

Exact steps to take if you want to follow my solution:

- Open VS installer
- Click MODIFY on the SKU of VS you were trying to use when you got the error (in my case the Preview version of VS enterprise)
- In the list of workloads make sure ASP.NET is checked, if not check it and click install

Comment: Can you give more details? What is SKU and where is the list of workloads?

Answer (score 8):

This happened for me with an update to VS 2019.  What I did was:

1. Open Visual Studio Installer.
2. Click Modify
3. Click "Development time IIS support" under ".NET cross-platform development"
4. Click Modify

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: It was listed under the ASP.Net workload for me as shown here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/development-time-iis-support-for-asp-net-core-applications/

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is installing .NET Core hosting bundle from here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/1/381CBBF3-36DA-4983-BFF3-5881548A70BE/DotNetCore.1.0.4_1.1.1-WindowsHosting.exe

**Update:**

Last available version can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer)

Just install it and start your project using IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's unclear if you are trying to host them in IIS or not (this message should only appear when you try to host it on IIS)... a shoot into the blue.

The ASPNetCoreModule isn't installed by default iirc, not even with VS2015/2017 tools. You can download and install them from the official .NET Core download page [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime).

You need the "Windows Server Hosting (x64 & x86)".

Comment: I am not hosting my application at IIS, what I do is I am trying to run the ASP.NET Core project locally at my PC from Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Please, see my question again, I've attached an image about what SDK are installed. Shoud I install "Windows Server Hosting (x64 & x86)"?

Comment: I've installed this package (`.NET Core 1.1.1 runtime (Current)`). However, there is still the same error. May be another suggestions?

Comment: The error message is not about the runtime, it's about the IIS module. ASPNETCoreModule is a specialized fork of HttpPlattformHandler (an IIS Module for Http Listener and proxy requests). This **is not part of the runtime**. It should normally be installed with a) .NET Tools for Visual Studio 2015 (or with VS2017 installer since .NET is built-in) or via the ""Windows Server Hosting (x64 & x86)" download on the .NET Core download page, **not** ".NET Core 1.1.1 runtime (Current)"

Comment: Normally "Windows Server Hosting (x64 & x86)" is for Server usage, where you only install runtime + the module, w/o the VS2015 tools (you typically don't have VS2017 running on your webserver :P)

Comment: I've already installed the following software `DotNetCore.1.0.4_1.1.1-WindowsHosting`, however I still get the same error `The ASPNETCoreModule which is required to host .NET Core projects in IIS does not appear to be installed. Try repairing Visual Studio to correct the problem.` In addition, I've tried to repair my Visual Studio 2015. Please, may be you have another suggestions?

Comment: Not really... Switch to VS2017. It installs and updates faster and will be the only one which support future versions of the dotnet tools/build pipeline. The old project.json related tools won't be updated anymore, they are deprecated. So it's unavoidable to switch to vs2017 at some point

Comment: please, see my question again. I've attached the image about what I've installed that you gave me advice. Is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142154/discussion-between-stepup-and-tseng).

Answer (score 2):

check `IIS Express` on `Vs2017 installer`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after updating from 16.9 to 16.10. repairing the Visual Studio fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It can come from a .NET Core SDK missing or a version mismatch. Does your project have a global.json ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/global-json))? If not, try to use it to specify the version of the .NET Core SDK to use. Be careful though, the version to specify isn't the "public forward" one, it can be a little counterintuitive.

EDIT: Now that I think about it, are you sure you installed the .NET Core SDK for Visual Studio 2015? I can't remember if it is provided out of the box.

Comment: Please, see my question again, I've attached an image about what SDK are installed. Shoud I install "Windows Server Hosting (x64 & x86)"?

Comment: It can't hurt to try. I'm sure I had this message before and it was a version mismatch between the project structure (xproj, project.json or csproj) and the tooling I had. By default it will take the latest tooling.

Comment: So I need to change version from `"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"` to `"version": "1.0.3-preview2-003131"` ?

Comment: Go here "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk" on your disk to see the versions you have

Comment: I've changed this parameter. Nothing happened. I still get the same error.

Comment: Then I guess this is a dead end, maybe the ASPNetCoreModule is actually missing. Don't forget to post your solution once you solved it.